# where to find chrome apps directory r/w api?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I read from http://www.marshut.com/yyhrq/brackets-as-a-chrome-app-with-live-development-directory-access-demo-inside.html
that chrome app has a brand new directory r/w API. does someone know where to find the documentation about it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find info on chrome.fileSystem [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem), which is how you get hold of DirectoryEntry objects. You can find info on how to use these [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/).

There are also a sample app tying these both together [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/filesystem-access).